# como quitar la apariencia de link

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer que los iconos no tengan apariencia de link, así están:

[image: iconos con decoración de enlace]

este es mi codigo en HTML:

```html
<ul id="redesSociales">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=es-la" rel="nofollow target= _blank><li id="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><li id="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></li>
  </a>
  <a href="https://co.pinterest.com/"><li id="Pinterest"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

y este es el de CSS:

```css
footer .footerWeb #instagram,
footer .footerWeb #Facebook,
footer .footerWeb #likedin,
footer .footerWeb #Pinterest {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: el `a` ponelo dentro del `li` sino el browser te va a cambiar el html final para tener un dom coherente ( `ul` = lista sin orden, `li` = item de lista  )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A todos tus elementos `a` agregales la propiedad  `text-decoration: none;`

En tu css agrega lo siguiente:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fuentes:

[text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Comment: el text-decoration lo pongo solo en css, o tambien en html ? @NikolaTesla

Comment: @JoséHernandez Las reglas css se deben declarar solo en tu archivo de estilos, mezclar css con HTML no es una buena práctica

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM

Answer (score 2):

no te olvides de agregar a tu css

```
footer .footerWeb #instagram,
  footer .footerWeb #Facebook,
  footer .footerWeb #likedin,
  footer .footerWeb #Pinterest{
    list-style: none !important;
    display: inline-flex !important;
   }
```

El !important es por si tiene otro css que afecte los elementos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad de css

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Eso deberia quitarle el subrayado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar esto. hace que todos los estados del link se vean de un mismo color, no importa si ya fueron visitados antes (morado), si el cursor está encima, etc.

```css
a:link, :visited, :hover, :active{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Sino podrías especificar el hover si así lo deseás, obviamente. Ej:

```css
a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Normalmente son los pseudo-elementos los que llevan 2 puntos `::`. `hover` no es un pseudo-elemento y se escribe con uno solo `a:hover`.

Comment: Sep, me di cuenta del error y vine a editarlo, gracias por aclararlo.